# How can I implement for loop in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to develop for loop so that I don't have to execute a command for each value in array B. I want output in one array.
How can I do it here in Python for the below code?

```
C=[ 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 8, 3, 6, 6, 7, 11,  8, 10, 23,22, 12, 15, 34, 16,  9, 11,  6,  0,  0]
B= np.array([500,  1000,  1500,  2000,  2500,  3000,  3500,  4000,  4500,5000,  5500,  6000,  6500,  7000,  7500,  8000,  8500,  9000,9500, 10000, 10500, 11000, 11500, 12000])
C=[ 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 8, 3, 6, 6, 7, 11,  8, 10, 23,22, 12, 15, 34, 16,  9, 11,  6,  0,  0]
B= np.array([500,  1000,  1500,  2000,  2500,  3000,  3500,  4000,  4500,5000,  5500,  6000,  6500,  7000,  7500,  8000,  8500,  9000,9500, 10000, 10500, 11000, 11500, 12000])
EU=np.array(C)*np.array(B)
ENU_1 =np.where(B < 500, 0, (B-500)*C)
ENU_2 =np.where(B < 1000, 0, (B-1000)*C)
```

Comment: With all due respect, there must be already thousands of online resources in which the basics of Python are explained... See for example: https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop.

Answer (score 1):

Create both *B* and *C* as *Numpy* arrays:

```
C = np.array([ 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 8, 3, 6, 6, 7, 11, 8, 10, 23, 22, 12, 15, 34, 16,
    9, 11, 6, 0, 0])
B = np.array([500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 3000, 3500, 4000, 4500, 5000, 5500,
    6000, 6500, 7000, 7500, 8000, 8500, 9000, 9500, 10000, 10500, 11000, 11500,
    12000])
```

Then compute *EU* just as multiplication of both source arrays, without any loop:

```
EU = C * B
```

And the rest of your code (to compute *ENU_1* and *ENU_2*) is OK.

But you wrote that you wanted the output in **one** array and this is unclear.
Do you want to **concatenate** 3 arrays computed so far?

If this is the case, run e.g.:

```
result = np.concatenate((EU, ENU_1, ENU_2))
```

Note double parentheses, because:

- the external parentheses are a "container" for parameters,
- the interal parentheses (with what is inside) create a **tuple** - the
  first (and only) parameter of this function - the sequence of arrays
  to concatenate.